# In sybase: how to conditionally drop table and deallocate cursor

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

In postgres I can do:

```
drop table if exists ...
```

But in sybase I have to do:

```
if exists(
select 1 from sysobjects where name=... and type='U'
)
drop table ...
```

Is this the way to go in sybase?

But how do I do this for:

```
deallocate cursor ...
```

? In which system table is a cursor?

Also, I saw that in a procedure, the cursor is gone after the procedure has executed, so in a procedure I do not have to deallocate a cursor at the end. But if the procedure create a table, it is still there after the procedure has executed. Is this true indeed?

Comment: You wouldn't generally have drop/create actual user tables in a database within Sybase stored procedures on the fly like that. You can use #tables for temporary work areas for a procedure which are automatically cleaned up when the session exits rather than real/permanent ones.

A cursor isnt a system table object which is why you deallocate - you can't deallocate a cursor which doesn't exist (you'll get an error) so you don't need to check for its existence, just deallocate it. It's good practice to ALWAYS clean up and deallocate your cursors.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. But in my case in a procedure I run a query and  the resultset I select into in a table, and after the procedure has finished I use bcp to export this table in a csv file (which another program uses), and after that I drop the table. So how would you do that?

Comment: You can use a permanent tempdb table for that e.g. tempdb..<tablename> or ##tablename (which is the same thing) as then you have the tablename to bcp out from directly. This avoids any contention in your system tables like sysobjects and syscolumns in your main user database as an extra benefit which can be useful on busy databases. More info here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X10118.htm

You can also BCP out of a view directly as well depending on how complex your resultset is to create so that could also be an option.